# What's the equivalent of “premature ejaculation” medical condition in female sexual health?

Tags: sex

I don't believe this line:

> men are from Mars and women from Venus.

From [here](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/all-about-sex/201103/all-orgasms-are-the-same-different), I learned that men and women feel orgasm same but different.

Premature ejaculation (PE) is when ejaculation happens sooner than a man or his partner would like during sex.

So what's the equivalent of "premature ejaculation" medical condition in female sexual health?

Comment: Why do you think PE is a medical condition? Men can train themselves to delay ejaculation almost indefinitely.

Comment: @CareyGregory Anything that creates a suffering or distress in patients is considered a medical condition, at least in modern definitions of illnesses (WHO: Health is a state of complete physical, mental and social well-being and not merely the absence of disease or infirmity), although [some consider it not a disease](https://doi.org/10.1002%2Fca.22655). There appear to be pathological reasons for it (prostatitis).

Comment: @Narusan Barring physical pathology or perhaps drugs, I would view it as the authors of the link you provided do. It can be prevented with training, so arguably it's an acquired habit rather than a medical condition.

Comment: @CareyGregory I agree. I will argue however that a habit causing distress and suffering may be called a medical condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always hard to prove a negative, but I don't think such a condition exists.

*Premature Female Orgasm* appears to be the term you are looking for, and apparently there [has been a patent filed by Pfizer](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2005/jul/29/sciencenews.medicineandhealth1), but I couldn't find any references in literature (Google Scholar, Web of Knowledge) so I guess from a medical perspective, this condition has not been described.

It is here where @CareyGregory's comment comes into play: Premature Ejaculation is defined as *[an ejaculation that always or nearly always occurs prior to or within about 1 minute of vaginal penetration from the first sexual experience (lifelong PE) or a clinically significant and bothersome reduction in latency time, often to about 3 minutes or less (acquired PE)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5001991/)*, but one can argue whether statistical deviations from the norm alone provide for pathogenity.

For females a likewise definition would be an orgasm prior to a certain time after vaginal penetration. Whether this would have any clinical significance can be doubted. Furthermore, unless women express suffering or distress from such a condition (as yet unreported in literature), calling it a condition remains questionable.